# Generar variable aleatoria distribución uniforme discreta con parámetro variable

Tags: r, random

Estoy haciendo algunas simulaciones y necesito generar un vector de variable aleatoria uniforme discreta con parámetros (min=0, max=x). Para entender el problema a detalle, supongamos el siguiente data.frame:

```
> df <-data.frame(x=base::sample(0:10, size=5, replace=TRUE))
> df
   x
1  8
2  7
3  0
4 10
5  2
```

Para la primera fila quiero obtener un valor aleatorio que provenga de una discreta uniforme U(0,8), en la segunda, de una U(0,7) y la misma lógica para las demás filas.

He probado con:

```
#primera opcion
df$y<-base::sample(0:df$x, size=5, replace=TRUE)
#segunda opcion
df$y<-t(apply(df,1, function(x) base::sample(0:df$x, size=1, replace=TRUE)))
```

Pero en ambos casos aparece warning aclarando que solo usa el valor de x en la primera fila

```
In 0:df$x : numerical expression has 10 elements: only the first used
```

Esperaría no tener que recurrir a un loop o a un round(runif(...))

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con `df$y <- sapply(df$x, function(x) sample(0:x, 1))`

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 1):

El principal problema que veo, es este `0:df$x`, entiendo lo que buscas hacer, pero no es de esta forma. La clausula `n:m` genera una secuencia numérica y es una generalización de `seq()` que define los parámetros `from` y `to` como vectores de longitud 1, en tu caso `df$x` no lo es, sino que es un vector de longitud igual al número de filas. Es como si hicieras algo así:

```
0:c(1,2,3)

[1] 0 1
Warning message:
In 0:c(1, 2, 3) : numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

La secuencia final solo toma el primer elemento del vector `c(1,2,3)`.

Lo que buscas, en realidad sería algo así:

```
df$y <- apply(df[,1,drop=FALSE], 1, FUN = function(x) list(sample(0:x, size=5, replace=TRUE)))

   x               y
1  8   6, 4, 5, 3, 2
2  7   7, 5, 0, 1, 7
3  0   0, 0, 0, 0, 0
4 10 2, 0, 10, 1, 10
5  2   2, 2, 2, 0, 2
```

Usar `apply` te obliga a hacer esto: `df[,1,drop=FALSE]` para que si requieres una columna, esta no se transforme automáticamente en un vector, y se mantenga su naturaleza de `data.frame`. Luego se trata de definir la función que vamos aplicar para cada elemento, esta función recibirá un parámetro que en este caso será cada fila (`MARGIN=1`) y sobre dicha fila, que, cosa importante solo tiene una columna, haremos el `sample()` apropiado.

O bien, de forma mucho más compacta, mediante `lapply()`:

```
df$y <- lapply(df$x, function(x) sample(0:x, size=5, replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: Gracias por la explicación. Las dos alternativas funcionan perfecto pero prefiero lapply por la brevedad del código.